# Basic help with factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I am having a small problem recalling how to factor with exponents and roots.

For example, I  understand $\sqrt{16t^2+4t^4}$=$2t\sqrt{4+t^2}$

But I have issues when it is factoring not with a square root, but say a (3/2) for example.

For instance , in my book it writes $$(4e^{2t}+4e^{4t})^{3/2}=8e^{3t}(1+e^{2t})^{3/2}$$

And I don't see exactly how it is done. So I am looking for tips in general on how to understand this, and for factoring out with roots in general. Thanks

Comment: take it to the power of $\frac{2}{3}$ both sides

Comment: Remember $x^{3/2}$ is the same as $\sqrt{x^3}$ which is also the same as $(\sqrt{x})^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the thing to notice, when looking at $(4e^{2t} + 4e^{4t})^{3/2}$, is that the two terms $4e^{2t}$ and $4e^{4t}$ have a common factor: each is a multiple of $4e^{2t}$.  So one can extract that common factor as follows:  $$\begin{align}
(4e^{2t} + 4e^{4t})^{3/2}& = (4e^{2t}(1+e^{2t}))^{3/2} \\
& = (4e^{2t})^{3/2}(1+e^{2t})^{3/2} \\
& = 4^{3/2}(e^{2t})^{3/2}(1+e^{2t})^{3/2}  \\
& = 8\cdot e^{3t}\cdot (1+e^{2t})^{3/2}
\end{align}$$

(If any part of this wasn't clear, please leave a comment, and I will explain.)

Trying a similar thing with $\sqrt{16t^2 + 4t^4}$ also works: the two terms $16t^2$ and $4t^4$ have a common factor of $4t^2$, so let's extract that:

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{16t^2 + 4t^4}& = \sqrt{(4t^2)(4+t^2)}\\
&= \sqrt{4t^2}\sqrt{4+t^2} \\
&= 2t\sqrt{4+t^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: $\sqrt{t^2}=|t|$

Answer (score 0):

$$(4e^{2t}+4e^{4t})^{3/2}= \left(4e^{2t}(1+e^{2t})\right)^{3/2}=\left(4e^{2t}\right)^{3/2}\left(1+e^{2t}\right)^{3/2}=(4)^{3/2}(e^{2t})^{3/2}\left(1+e^{2t}\right)^{3/2}=8e^{3t}(1+e^{2t})^{3/2}$$